# How to style a button on a Contact Form 7? Or add my own button

Tags: wordpress

```css
.btn.btn-decor {
    min-width: 12.375rem;
    color: #fff;
    padding: .625rem;
    background: #000;
    border: none;
        outline: none;

}
.btn {
    -webkit-transition: color .3s linear,border-color .3s linear,background .3s linear;
    transition: color .3s linear,border-color .3s linear,background .3s linear;
    min-width: 11.1875rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .6875rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: normal;
    padding: 1.25rem .9375rem;
    position: relative;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: .730rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;

}
.btn.btn-decor span {
    -webkit-transition: border-color .3s linear;
    transition: border-color .3s linear;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.25rem .9375rem;
    border-top: 2px solid #272726;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #272726;
    position: relative;

    }
    .btn.btn-decor span:before {
    bottom: 0;
}
.btn.btn-decor span:after, .btn.btn-decor span:before {
    -webkit-transition: border-color .3s linear;
    transition: border-color .3s linear;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1.375rem;
    border-width: 0 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #272726;
    color: #272726;
}
.btn.btn-decor .icon-star:first-child {
    left: -.25rem;
}
.btn.btn-decor .icon-star {
    -webkit-transition: color .4s linear,-webkit-transform .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear,-webkit-transform .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear,transform .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear,transform .4s linear,-webkit-transform .4s linear;
    width: .625rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0);
    font-size: .625rem;
    color: #272726;
}
[class*=" icon-"], [class^=icon-] {
    font-family: icomoon!important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.btn.btn-decor .icon-star:nth-child(2) {
    right: -.25rem;
}
.btn.btn-decor .icon-star {
    -webkit-transition: color .4s linear,-webkit-transform .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear,-webkit-transform .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear,transform .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear,transform .4s linear,-webkit-transform .4s linear;
    width: .625rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0);
    font-size: .625rem;
    color: #272726;
    }
    [class*=" icon-"], [class^=icon-] {
    font-family: icomoon!important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.btn.btn-decor span:after {
    top: 0;
}
.btn.btn-decor span:after, .btn.btn-decor span:before {
    -webkit-transition: border-color .3s linear;
    transition: border-color .3s linear;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1.375rem;
    border-width: 0 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #272726;
    color: #272726;
}
.icon-star:before {
    content: url("");
}
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn.btn-decor.btn-decor-white:hover .icon-star,.btn.btn-decor:hover .icon-star {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
    color: #4f4f4d
}
.offer-section .stars-bg .icon-star:first-child {
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%)
}
.btn.btn-decor.btn-decor-white:hover span,.btn.btn-decor:hover span {
    border-color: #4f4f4d
}

.btn.btn-decor.btn-decor-white:hover span:after,.btn.btn-decor.btn-decor-white:hover span:before,.btn.btn-decor:hover span:after,.btn.btn-decor:hover span:before {
    border-color: #4f4f4d
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a -label="Link more" href="#" gv-link="link_3" class="btn btn-decor js-check-text sticky-link">
       <span><i class="icon-star"></i>submit<i class="icon-star"></i></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39qna.jpg)
When adding my button classes to the shortcode, it picks them up, but not correctly. Maybe because I have two classes  "btn btn-decor" and "icon-star". What other options can there be, well, besides creating your own form, so that the button works in the created Contact Form 7?

Comment: Update the question with the shortcode and how you add the classes. The output that you get and the expected output that you want. Now it's not clear at all.

Comment: I made some changes. The picture shows the result of adding my classes to the form. If you look at the code, then this is what I would like to get in the form.